How can I get ZSH to pick up my latest version of Bash
My current shell is ZSH and it defaults to using Bash version 3.2.x. I'm on macos Sonoma version 14.3.1.
For one of the shell commands I'm trying to run, I'm currently getting the below error:
unbound variable and this requires using a version of bash >=4 for using a functionality with associative arrays.
I've installed the latest version of bash using brew and its currently available on this path:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin/bash
In my .zshrc I'm trying to add export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin" as a way to append the path to the latest version of bash that I want to use
But when I do bash --version I still get 3.2.57:
➜  ~ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

How do I configure ZSH to load/use the latest bash version to solve the unbound variable error?
My /etc/shells looks like below(I updated it to add the latest bash version installed through brew):
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin/bash


Just write your script in zsh?

When you do
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin"

you're making your new directory the LAST place to look for an instance of bash, you should have done
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin:$PATH"

to make it the first directory instead, otherwise some existing version of bash will be picked up by anything looking down your PATH.
Also, make sure in your script you have a shebang of #!/usr/bin/env bash at the top of your script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$BASH_VERSION" >&2     # just so you can see which version is used
...

so it actually looks in your PATH for bash.

Thank you Ed, for your answer and especially for the explanation of why $PATH needs to be added to the end.

The directories listed in PATH are checked from left to right, and the first match wins. Therefore, putting the bash directory at the end of your PATH does not help much.
However, if you have a script which requires a particular bash version, I would not rely on the PATH variable at all. Either I would use a #! line for the script pointing to the desired bash version, make the script executable and then run it just with SCRIPTNAME. Or alternatively, don't care about the #! and execute the script with
 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin/bash SCRIPTNAME

Since this is awkward to type, you could consider using symbolic links:
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash5

and then (on the reasonable assumption that you have /usr/local/bin in your PATH) run it with
bash5 SCRIPTNAME

